# Magento 2 add text input to massaction from dropdown

Tags: magento2, controllers, admin-controller, massaction, input

In magento 1, if I wanted to add a text input to send a custom value with my massaction to my controller, I would do something like:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('add_ship_method', array(
    'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Add Shipping Method'),
    'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/custom_admin_route/changeship'),
    'additional' => array(
        'ship_method' => array(
            'name' => 'ship_method',
            'type' => 'text',
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'label' => 'Shipping Method'
        )
    )
);
```

But for Magento 2, I'm at a loss for how to add a custom text input, similar to the functionality described above.

It seems like a pretty simple feature to add, so I'm assuming I'm just not googling the right thing.